# Substitute the variables of a polynomial with caracas (Sympy)

Tags: python, r, sympy

I have a long polynomial in four variables x, y, z, w:

```
((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2
```

I'm working with R. I want to use the **caracas** package (a wrapper of Sympy) to get this expression as a polynomial *after doing a change of variables*. Namely, I want to substitue x, y, z and w by

```
a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w,
a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z,
a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y,
a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x
```

respectively. I tried `subs` with no luck. Here is the only working way I found:

```
library(caracas)
def_sym(x, y, z, w, a, b, c, d)
X <- a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w
Y <- a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z
Z <- a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y
W <- a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x

expr <- ((X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*Z^2+16*W^2))^2*((X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)^2+296*(X^2+Y^2)-4*(9*Z^2+16*W^2)) -16*(X^2+Y^2)*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)^2*(37*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)^2-1369*(X^2+Y^2)-7*(225*Z^2+448*W^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(X^3-3*X*Y^2)*(110*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)^3 -148*(X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2+145/3)*(110*X^2+110*Y^2-297*Z^2+480*W^2)) -64*(X^2+Y^2)*(3*(729*Z^4+4096*W^4)+168*(X^2+Y^2)*(15*Z^2-22*W^2)) +64*(12100/27*(X^3-3*X*Y^2)^2 -7056*(3*X^2*Y-Y^3)^2) -592240896*Z^2*W^2

poly <- sympy_func(
  expr, "Poly", domain = "QQ[a,b,c,d]"
)
```

But after 30 minutes the computation of `poly` is not finished. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: There are more efficient ways to do this in SymPy but either way the expression you are trying to compute will be huge so actually the most efficient approach is potentially not trying to compute the fully expanded polynomial here. It depends what you actually want to do with `poly` after.

Comment: I need all the coefficients of the monomials composing the polynomial. So it needs to be expanded.

Comment: When you say "no luck", come what failed? Did you try use the `simultaneous=True` or else do `eq.xreplace({x: a*x - b*y..., y:, etc...})`?

Comment: @smichr The substitution works in Python. I didn't manage to get it in R (the syntax is different). But well, it's not dramatic if I have to wait 30 minutes (I have only one polynomial to deal with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than generating the full expression and then requesting coefficients of the expansion when you are done, you can take it term-by-term. I have done so twice with the full expression, but you can do so with the toy expression that is followed by your full expression as a comment:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d
eq = x*y + 1#parse_expr('((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2', transformations=T[:])
reps = {x: a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w,y:a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z,z:a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y,w:a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x}
eq = eq.xreplace(reps)
c = {}
for i in Add.make_args(eq):
    f = i.xreplace(reps).expand()
    for s in Add.make_args(f):
        co, mo = s.as_coeff_mul(x,y,z,w)
        c.setdefault(Mul._from_args(mo), []).append(co)

for k in c:
    print(k,Add(*c[k])))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. There is italic in the block codes, looks like a bug, I've never seen that before.

Comment: But don't we loose the rational numbers with this way? If I use **eq = x*y + 1/2**, then **1/2** becomes **0.5**.

Comment: If you parse '1/2' it will remain `1/2`; if you enter it raw, it will become 0.5.

Comment: I hadn't seen italics in indented code, either, before. [Henry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) edit taught me that I can use the normal triple backtic+python to signify code. (Thanks, Henry.

Comment: Ok I get the **1/2**. I expected an answer with R+caracas but this looks complicated, especially to reproduce the **for** loops. So I accept your purely Pythonic answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on clarificaitons to the question in the comments we are assuming that what is wanted is to expand the result into a polynomial in x, y, z and w such that the coefficients are polynomials in a, b, c, d and the output is the exponents of each monomial and corresponding coefficient polynomials expressed in terms of a, b, c and d.

This uses character substitution creating `ch2` and then invokes `mp` from the mpoly package to create an mpoly object. Internally these are made of a list of monomials.  We define and use `f` to iterate through the list extracting the coefficients in a, b, c and d and the monomials in x, y, z, w.  Use `tapply` to collect and sum all a, b, c, d coefficients of the same x, y, z, w monomial.  `result` is a character vector of a, b, c, d coefficients and the names are the x, y, z, w monomials.

On a relatively slow laptop this took 286 seconds.

```
library(magrittr) 
library(mpoly)

pt <- proc.time()[[3]]

ch <- "((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2"

ch2 <- ch %>%
  gsub("([xyzw])", "\\1_", .) %>%
  gsub("x_", "(a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w)", .) %>%
  gsub("y_", "(a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z)", .) %>%
  gsub("z_", "(a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y)", .) %>%
  gsub("w_", "(a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x)", .)

p <- mp(ch2)

# x is a component of an mpoly.  names are variables to extract 
# plus "coef" or if "coef" not among names then coef is set to 1.
# output is character vector.
f <- function(x, names) {
   names2 <- unique(c(names, "coef"))
   x0 <- x[names(x) %in% names2]
   if (!"coef" %in% names) x0["coef"] <- 1
   p <- structure(list(x0), class = "mpoly")
   print(p, stars = TRUE, silent = TRUE)
}

xx <- sapply(exponents(p), function(x) toString(x[c("x","y","z","w")]))
aa <- sapply(p, f, c("a", "b", "c", "d", "coef"))
r <- tapply(aa, xx, paste, collapse = "+")
r <- paste(names(r), unname(r), sep = ", ")

proc.time()[[3]] - pt
## [1] 285.94
```

Comment: I get: **Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument**.

Comment: Ok, works with **x = _**.

Comment: Terrific. I didn't know that **mpoly** can deal with symbolic coefficients. But the rational numbers are replaced with their decimal approximation.

Comment: Have fixed it now.

Comment: I can multiply by 27 to get rid of the fractions, fine. My goal is to copy the resulting expression to POV-Ray, and then the asterisks for the multiplications are needed. I expected to get them with **mp(ch2, stars_only = TRUE)** but no, unfortunately.

Comment: I need the coefficients of the monomial terms actually. That's why I use Sympy, which allows to deal with polynomials on **Q(a, b, c, d)**.

Comment: No this is not what I want. I want a polynomial in x, y, z, w only, not in x, y, z, w, a, b, c, d. So the coefficients must contain the letters a, b, c, d. This is not possible.

Comment: See my blog to see what I mean: https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/caracas01.html

Comment: Have revised to produce coefficients in terms of a, b, c, d.

Comment: Good work! But I need to separate the monomials. I finally managed with caracas (<https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/caracas02.html>). It takes 20 minutes.

Comment: Have revised to output the exponents of each x,y,z,w monomial followed by the coefficient polynomial in terms of a, b, c, ,d.  Also switched to magrittr so it can be run on older versions of R as well.

Comment: Amazing. It would be nice to have such a functionality in a package. My package **gmpoly** deals with polynomials with rational coefficients, but I don't know whether one can use it here (I don't well remember what this package does exactly). In the meantime, I did my expansion with Julia <https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/juliaPolynomialExpansion.html>, it is incredibly fast.

Comment: G. Grothendieck> I've found a faster solution with **spray**. I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

This is also using SymPy from Python but might be easier to translate to R:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d,t

eq = sympify('((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2')
reps = {x: a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w,y:a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z,z:a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y,w:a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x}
result = poly(eq.xreplace(reps).subs(sqrt(3), t), domain=QQ)
result = poly(result.as_expr().subs(t, sqrt(3)))
```

Note that I used lower case `poly` rather than `Poly` because it is faster. I think also that replacing `sqrt(3)` with a symbol `t` speeds things up a lot during the expansion in `poly`. Lastly installing gmpy2 alongside SymPy will make this sort of thing a lot faster.

With that you can then convert it to a string (it sounds like that's what you want to do). The result has over a million characters but I'll just show the first 1000:

```py
In [22]: s = str(result)

In [23]: len(s)
Out[23]: 1603555

In [24]: s[:1000]
Out[24]: 'Poly(x**12*a**12 + 6*x**12*a**10*b**2 + 6*x**12*a**10*c**2 + 6*x**12*a**10*d**2 + 15*x**12*a**8*b**4 + 30*x**12*a**8*b**2*c**2 + 30*x**12*a**8*b**2*d**2 + 15*x**12*a**8*c**4 + 30*x**12*a**8*c**2*d**2 + 15*x**12*a**8*d**4 + 20*x**12*a**6*b**6 + 60*x**12*a**6*b**4*c**2 + 60*x**12*a**6*b**4*d**2 + 60*x**12*a**6*b**2*c**4 + 120*x**12*a**6*b**2*c**2*d**2 + 60*x**12*a**6*b**2*d**4 + 20*x**12*a**6*c**6 + 60*x**12*a**6*c**4*d**2 + 60*x**12*a**6*c**2*d**4 + 20*x**12*a**6*d**6 + 15*x**12*a**4*b**8 + 60*x**12*a**4*b**6*c**2 + 60*x**12*a**4*b**6*d**2 + 90*x**12*a**4*b**4*c**4 + 180*x**12*a**4*b**4*c**2*d**2 + 90*x**12*a**4*b**4*d**4 + 60*x**12*a**4*b**2*c**6 + 180*x**12*a**4*b**2*c**4*d**2 + 180*x**12*a**4*b**2*c**2*d**4 + 60*x**12*a**4*b**2*d**6 + 15*x**12*a**4*c**8 + 60*x**12*a**4*c**6*d**2 + 90*x**12*a**4*c**4*d**4 + 60*x**12*a**4*c**2*d**6 + 15*x**12*a**4*d**8 + 6*x**12*a**2*b**10 + 30*x**12*a**2*b**8*c**2 + 30*x**12*a**2*b**8*d**2 + 60*x**12*a**2*b**6*c**4 + 120*x**12*a**2*b**6*c**2*d**2 + 60'
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need a polynomial in x, y, z, w, to extract the coefficients of all monomials composing this polynomial. The symbols a, b, c, d must be considered as constant. So one need to work in **QQ(a, b, c, d, t)**.

Comment: You can use something like `result.as_expr().as_poly(x, y, z, w)` to get that form.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of smichr's answer, I finally managed to get what I want in R. Here is an example shorter than my real case.

```r
library(caracas)
sympy <- get_sympy()

# define the variables x,y,z and the constants a,b
# as well as auxiliary variables X,Y,Z
def_sym(x, y, z, a, b, X, Y, Z)

# define expression in terms of X,Y,Z
expr <- sympy$parse_expr("X**2 + X*Z/3 + Y + 1/2") 

# define the substitutions in new variables
Xs <- a*x + b*y
Ys <- x + 9*z
Zs <- a*y + z^2

# define the list of replacements
substitutions <- list(
  X = Xs$pyobj,
  Y = Ys$pyobj,
  Z = Zs$pyobj
)

# perform the substitutions
expr <- expr$subs(substitutions)

# extraction of monomials in the 'povray' list
povray <- list()
terms <- sympy$Add$make_args(expr)
for(term in terms){
  f <- term$expand()
  fterms <- sympy$Add$make_args(f)
  for(fterm in fterms){
    decomp <- fterm$as_coeff_mul(x$pyobj, y$pyobj, z$pyobj)
    coef <- decomp[[1]]
    mono <- decomp[[2]]
    polexpr <- sympy$Mul$fromiter(mono)
    poly <- polexpr$as_poly(x$pyobj, y$pyobj, z$pyobj)
    degree <- toString(poly$monoms()[[1]])
    if(degree %in% names(povray)){
      povray[[degree]] <- sympy$Add(povray[[degree]], coef)
    }else{
      povray[[degree]] <- coef
    }
  }
}

polynomial <- vapply(names(povray), function(degree){
  sprintf("xyz(%s): %s,", degree, povray[[degree]])
}, character(1L))
cat(polynomial, sep = "\n")
# xyz(0, 0, 0): 1/2,
# xyz(1, 0, 0): 1,
# xyz(2, 0, 0): a**2,
# xyz(0, 2, 0): a*b/3 + b**2,
# xyz(1, 1, 0): a**2/3 + 2*a*b,
# xyz(0, 0, 1): 9,
# xyz(1, 0, 2): a/3,
# xyz(0, 1, 2): b/3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure R solution using the **spray** package:

```r
library(spray)

f <- function(x, y, z, w) {
  ((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2
}

x <- lone(1, 8)
y <- lone(2, 8)
z <- lone(3, 8)
w <- lone(4, 8)
a <- lone(5, 8)
b <- lone(6, 8)
c <- lone(7, 8)
d <- lone(8, 8)

X <- a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w
Y <- a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z
Z <- a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y
W <- a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x

P <- f(X, Y, Z, W)

nterms <- length(P)
coeffs <- P[["value"]]

XYZW_powers <- P[["index"]][, c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)]
XYZW <- apply(XYZW_powers, 1L, function(comp) {
  sprintf("xyzw(%s): ", toString(comp))
})

ABCD_powers  <- P[["index"]][, c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L)]
ABCD_polys <- lapply(1L:nterms, function(i) {
  spray(ABCD_powers[i, ], coeffs[i])
})

ABCD <- split(ABCD_polys, XYZW)

ABCD_groups <- sapply(ABCD, function(polys) {
  polysum <- polys[[1]]
  for(poly in polys[-1]) {
    polysum <- spray_add(
      polysum$index, polysum$value, poly$index, poly$value
    )
  }
  as.spray(polysum)
}, simplify = FALSE)
ABCD_groups <- Filter(Negate(is.empty), ABCD_groups)

asCharacter <- function(poly) {
  op <- options(sprayvars = letters)
  x <- capture.output(print_spray_polyform(poly))
  options(op)
  paste0(x, collapse = " ")
}

ABchar <- sapply(ABCD_groups, asCharacter, simplify = FALSE)

head(ABchar, 2)
# $`xyzw(0, 0, 0, 0): `
# [1] "12749128107.8532"
# 
# $`xyzw(0, 0, 0, 10): `
# [1] "-60*c^4*d^6 +182*b^10 +1484*a^4*b^6 +2552*a^2*b^6*c^2 +722*b^8*d^2 +74*a^2*c^8 +3144*a^2*b^2*c^4*d^2 +632*b^2*c^2*d^6 +692*b^4*c^6 -30*c^2*d^8 +98*a^10 -60*c^6*d^4 +1068*b^6*d^4 +1068*a^4*c^2*d^4 +1880*a^6*b^2*d^2 +564*a^6*d^4 +1880*a^6*b^2*c^2 +296*a^2*c^6*d^2 +3324*a^4*b^4*c^2 +2196*a^4*b^2*c^4 +1316*a^6*b^4 +2552*a^2*b^6*d^2 -6*d^10 +574*a^8*b^2 +3144*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^4 +386*a^8*d^2 +1048*a^2*b^2*c^6 +356*a^4*c^6 +4392*a^4*b^2*c^2*d^2 +1068*b^6*c^4 +564*a^6*c^4 +74*a^2*d^8 -30*c^8*d^2 +2076*b^4*c^4*d^2 +2076*b^4*c^2*d^4 +296*a^2*c^2*d^6 +2196*a^4*b^2*d^4 +444*a^2*c^4*d^4 +2700*a^2*b^4*c^4 +386*a^8*c^2 +158*b^2*c^8 +1068*a^4*c^4*d^2 +1128*a^6*c^2*d^2 +632*b^2*c^6*d^2 +1048*a^2*b^2*d^6 +948*b^2*c^4*d^4 +3324*a^4*b^4*d^2 +2136*b^6*c^2*d^2 +692*b^4*d^6 +722*b^8*c^2 +158*b^2*d^8 +826*a^2*b^8 +5400*a^2*b^4*c^2*d^2 -6*c^10 +356*a^4*d^6 +2700*a^2*b^4*d^4"
```

It takes about one minute.